# Trying to get referenced Laravel Eloquent data from another table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm just learning Laravel, and this is probably super easy for someone experienced with the framework, but I'm trying to get data from a different table and not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I have two tables, `Users`, which has fields `first_name`, `last_name`, and `pair_id`.  The `pair_id` column is programmatically restricted to either `null` or an integer in two rows that designates a "pair".  The there's the `confirmed_pair` table that has one pair per row and has a unique `pair_id` column, that refers to the one in the `Users` table.

In the ConfirmedPair model, I did this:

```
class ConfirmedPair extends Model
{
    public function pair() {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'pair_id');
    }

    public function pair_names() {      // returns an array of names of the players in the confirmed pair
        $names = User::where("pair_id", $this->get(["pair_id"])[0]->pair_id)->get(['first_name','last_name']);
        if (count($names) == 2) {      // if this pair exists
            return [
                $names[0]['first_name']." ".$names[0]['last_name'],
                $names[1]['first_name']." ".$names[1]['last_name']
            ];
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

In the controller, I did this:

```
class PageController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $confirmed_pair = new ConfirmedPair;
        return view('page', compact('confirmed_pair'));
    }
}
```

And in the blade view if I do this:

```
@for ($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++)
    {{ $confirmed_pair->find($i)->pair_names()[0] }}<br>
@endfor
```

No matter what `$i`'s value is, it returns the values of confirmed_pair id #1.

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If `pair_id` is assigned to 2 users

```
class ConfirmedPair extends Model {

  public function pairs() {
      return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'pair_id', 'pair_id');
  }

  public function pair_names() {
     if ($this->pairs->count() != 2) return null;

     // $this->pairs returns you a Collection of Users
     // try to dd($this->pairs) to see in action 

     $pairs = $this->pairs->toArray();

     return [
        $pairs[0]['first_name']." ".$pairs[0]['last_name'],
        $pairs[1]['first_name']." ".$pairs[1]['last_name']
     ];

  }

}
```

---

Can be done better but for your case this should work.

Comment: Hmm, just changing the model like you showed results in a "Call to a member function count() on null" error when trying to load the page, referring to the first line of the pair_names method.

Comment: Do you have `pair_id` column in both tables? If so try `return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'pair_id', 'pair_id');`

Comment: I do have `pair_id` in both tables.  Changing the contents of `pair_names()` to that code gives me the error "Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany as array".

Comment: Now it should work :) I forgot to change the collection to array. That's where `dd()` is your friend to debug

Comment: So every time`$this->pairs` is referenced, it's returning null.  So any time I try to do anything with it, I get an error.

Comment: Does your pairs relationship work? _So every time$this->pairs is referenced, it's returning null_ - this indicates your relationship doesn't work. Make sure you map foreign_key and local_key properly